# sveltekit ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I am trying to create a sveltekit dashboard, I want to toggle my sidebar,  in my +page.svelte the dropdown and sidebar does not work. how do i get to write this code to get it working properly in sveltekit page using typescript. I tried doing this below and it did not work too, please how do i properly access the components and attributes. I have also added a checkbox to toggle the class but it does not work.

`<script type="ts">
 
let active = true;

</script>


<div class="h-screen overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center" style="background: #edf2f7;">
   <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={active} >
</div>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  


    <div class="bg-red-600">
     
      <span
        class="absolute text-white text-4xl top-5 left-4 cursor-pointer"  on:click="{() => active = !active }" >
        <i class="bi bi-filter-left px-2 bg-purple-500 rounded-md"></i>
      </span>
      <div 
      class:active={active} 
        class=" sidebar fixed top-0 bottom-0 lg:left-0 p-2 w-[300px] overflow-y-auto text-center bg-blue-900" >
        <div class="text-gray-100 text-xl">
          <div class="p-2.5 mt-1 flex items-center">
            <i class="bi bi-app-indicator px-2 py-1 rounded-md bg-blue-600"></i>
            <h1 class="font-bold text-gray-200 text-[15px] ml-3">Bugatom </h1>
            <i
              class="bi bi-x cursor-pointer ml-28 lg:hidden bg-green-500"
              on:click="{() => active = !active}"
            ></i>
          </div>
          <div class="my-2 bg-gray-600 h-[1px]"></div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="p-2.5 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer bg-gray-700 text-white"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-search text-sm"></i>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            class="text-[15px] ml-4 w-full bg-transparent focus:outline-none"
          />
        </div>
        <div
          class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i>
          <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Gallery Home</span>
        </div>
        <div
          class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-bookmark-fill"></i>
          <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Bookmark</span>
        </div>
        <div class="my-4 bg-gray-600 h-[1px]"></div>
        <div
          class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
          on:click="{() => active = !active}"
                >
          <i class="bi bi-chat-left-text-fill"></i>
          <div class="flex justify-between w-full items-center">
            <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Chatbox</span>
            <span class="text-sm rotate-180" id="arrow" class:rotate={active}> <!--class:rotate-0={active}-->
              <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="text-left text-sm mt-2 w-4/5 mx-auto text-gray-200 font-bold"
          id="submenu" 
        >
          <h1 class="cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-blue-600 rounded-md mt-1">
            Social
          </h1>
          <h1 class="cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-blue-600 rounded-md mt-1">
            Personal
          </h1>
          <h1 class="cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-blue-600 rounded-md mt-1">
            Friends
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div
          class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i>
        <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Logout</span>
    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
<style>
  .active{
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  .rotate{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
</style>`

Comment: You should *not* query the DOM in Svelte, nor use something like `onclick` or `classList`. Look at the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/) first.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable response,  have edited the code below but the on:click does not work in my +page.svelte

Comment: Please [learn about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I had already fixed it earlier, but you broke it again.

Comment: sorry about that  H.B please help me out

Comment: Your click handler makes no sense, the variable is misspelled and you did not modify the variable. Also, you should not add click handlers on just any element, they should be on semantically correct elements like `button`.

Comment: done some edits on the click handler

Comment: What is the problem? I can see classes being toggled. Did you define the classes accordingly?

Comment: i have added a checkbox and defined the active class but it still does not work. i have edited the code above as  it is in my +page.svelte

Comment: You are not using the `active` variable to toggle any classes any more...

Comment: Please can you check again

Comment: I was able to get this fixed using a form. Thank you

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Either add a proper answer (and accept it) or delete the question, if you think it will not be useful to anyone besides you.

Comment: code updated with working solution.. thanks H.B

Comment: I said **"add an answer"** not "put the answer in the question", which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Finally, Here is the updated code that worked, below is the working code in my +page.svelte
    <code> <script type="ts">
      import type { PageData } from './$types'
      export let data: PageData;
      import type { ActionData } from './$types'
      export let form: ActionData
      import { invalidateAll } from '$app/navigation'
      import { applyAction,enhance } from '$app/forms';
      import { page } from '$app/stores';
      
    let active = false;
    if (form?.mytoggler === true){
    active = true;
    }
    
    if (form?.mytoggler === false){
    active = false;
    }
    </script>
    
    <div class="h-screen overflow-hidden lg:ml-80 flex items-center justify-center bg-{data.main_color}-50" >
    </div>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
      
        <div class="">
          <form    id="log" class="sm:w-2/2 md:w-2/2 lg:w-1/2 lg:pl-10 space-y-4 " method="POST" action="?/togglar" use:enhance   >
            <input   id='toggledata' name='toggledata' type='hidden' value='false' 
    class='shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 pl-2 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md h-12'  />
    
          <button type='submit' class='absolute text-white text-4xl top-5 left-4 cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center   text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white w-10 h-10'><i class="bi bi-filter-left px-2 bg-{data.main_color}-500 rounded-md"></i></button>
    </form>
          <div class:active={active} 
          class=" sidebar fixed top-0 bottom-0 lg:left-0 p-2 w-[300px] overflow-y-auto text-center bg-{data.main_color}-500"  >
            <div class="" >
              <div class="p-2.5 mt-1 flex items-center">
                <i class="bi bi-app-indicator px-6 py-5 rounded-full bg-white"></i>
                <img class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full" src="../b.jpg" alt="userphoto">
              
                <h1 class="font-bold text-{data.main_color}-900 mt-2 text-left text-[16px] ml-3"> </h1> 
                <form    id="log" class="sm:w-2/2 md:w-2/2 lg:w-1/2 lg:pl-10 space-y-4 " method="POST" action="?/closetogglar" use:enhance   >
                  <input   id='closetoggledata' name='closetoggledata' type='hidden' value='true' 
          class='shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 pl-2 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md h-12'  />
          
                <button type='submit' alt='grty' class='w-10 h-10 absolute text-white  top-5 right-5 cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center  text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-{data.main_color}-400 '><i
                  class="bi bi-filter-left w-10 h-9 rounded-md text-4xl cursor-pointer bg-gray-900"></i> </button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="my-2 bg-transparent h-[1px]"></div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="p-2.5 flex items-center border-{data.main_color}-50 shadow rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer  bg-gray-200 text-{data.main_color}-900"
            >
              <i class="bi bi-search text-sm"></i>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search"
                class="text-[15px] ml-4 w-full bg-transparent focus:outline-none"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
            >
              <i class="bi bi-house-door-fill text-[20px]"></i>
              <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Home</span>
            </div>
            <div
              class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white"
            >
              <i class="bi bi-bookmark-fill text-[20px]"></i>
              <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Bookmark</span>
            </div>
            <div
              class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white">
            
              <i class="bi bi-chat-left-text-fill text-[20px]"></i>
              <div class="flex justify-between w-full items-center">
                <span class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold">Chatbox</span>
                <span class="text-sm rotate-180" id="arrow" class:rotate={active}>
                  <i class="bi bi-chevron-down "></i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div
            class="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 text-white" 
            >
            <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right text-[20px]"></i>
            <form action="/auth/logout" method="POST" use:enhance={() => {    
              return async ({ result }) => {
                invalidateAll();  
                await applyAction(result);
              }
            }}>
              <button class="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-200 font-bold" type="submit">Log out</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    
    
    <style>
     
     .active{
        visibility:hidden;
      }
      .rotate{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      
    </style>
    </code>  
    
    then here is the working code in my +page.server.ts
    <code> 
    import type { PageData, Actions } from './$types';
    export let form: Actions
    export let data: PageData;
    import {error, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
    import { invalid } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    import { PrismaClient} from '@prisma/client'
    
    import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
        if (!locals.user) {
          throw redirect(302, '/auth/login')
        }
    
      if (locals.user) {
        return {
          chosen_color: locals.colors.color,
          chosen_user: locals.user.email
        };
      }
    }
    
    let toggleme = false;
    export const actions = {
/*
//code for the login
 defaulty: async (event: { request: { formData: () => any }, cookies: { set: (arg0: string, arg1: string, arg2: import('cookie').CookieSerializeOptions) => void; },  }) => {
        const form = await event.request.formData();
        const email = form.get('email');
        const password = form.get('password');   
        if (typeof email !== 'string' || !email.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) {
            return invalid(400, { email, emailinvalid: true });
        }
    if (!password  || typeof password !== 'string') {
        return invalid(400, { email, passwordmissing: true });
        }
       const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({  where: {email: email, },   })
     const passwordMatch =  user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.passwordHash)
          if (!user){
            return invalid(400, { email, wrongemail: true });
          }
          if (!passwordMatch){
            return invalid(400, { email, wrongpassword: true });
        }
    await prisma.$disconnect()
    console.log(error);
    },
*/
    togglar: async (event: { request: { formData: () => any; }; }) => {
      const forme = await event.request.formData();
      let toggledatay = forme.get('toggledata');
      return { toggledatay, mytoggler: false };
    }
    ,
    closetogglar: async (event: { request: { formData: () => any; }; }) => {
      const closeforme = await event.request.formData();
      let closetoggledatay = closeforme.get('closetoggledata');
      return { closetoggledatay, mytoggler: true };
    }
    }
    
    
    
    </code>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck